# Root partition size on hp-unix

Tags: unix, hp-ux

I have HP-Unix 11.11 installed on an HP-9000 series server. I want to know what happen to the server if the root partition gets full?  Will this affect the RAM or crash the server?  Also, will any applications running on the server be affected?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it'll do the same as any other operating system when the system disk fills to capacity. It will act erratically, some things will stop working or do subtly odd things, while others will appear to be fine.

This is one of those situations where you will experience undefined behaviour, which will more than likely differ every time it happens.

Basically, don't ever let your server get so low on disk space, or you're just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Pilbrow already said you can expect the gates of hell to break and all the possible horrors come out of it. I'd just add that a good rule of thumb is to never let available space go under 10%.

If you manage to really really fill it out, there's also the possibility that the system won't even boot correctly - it will boot but possibly not all services will start up.